# Kendo Grid Input TextBox Doesn't Pass Value

Tags: jquery, telerik, kendo-grid

In the header column of my Kendo Grid, I have created a search box.  The grid itself has autoBind set to false (to ensure the grid doesn't load until after the search button is clicked).  However, when the request data is sent to the controller, the value from the search box is always null.

In my debugging, I can confirm that the value entered into the text box is being captured as the .val(), and I've tried assigning the value to a variable first - and then assigning that variable to the model field (which is being passed to the controller).

All other field values on the page produce correct results, and hard-coding the field passes correctly.

Is there something that would keep the value of a textbox that's in the Kendo Grid from passing correctly?

```
headerTemplate: "Search Label &nbsp;<input id='searchInput' class='rptInputBxWidth'
     style='width:30%;' />&nbsp;<button id='SearchButton' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'
     onclick='loadPermitGrid()'><span data-tooltip='tooltip'class='fa fa-arrow-right'>&nbsp;
     Search</span></button>"
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the Kendo version I'm currently running loads the values on the loading of the page - so when the values are assigned (and passed), the initial loaded values are passed (even when these values are changed).

I ended up needing to direct the dataSource.read() function to pass the specific field to my controller.  This allowed me to pass the value as expected.